# Python issue with return statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code takes a list as input for example:

```
[1995, 1750, 2018]
```

and I am expecting it to give back
Basically, this code searches for the closest leap year for each year in a list of years

```
1996
1948
2016
```

all in a separate line.

The output I get back with the return statement is:

```
1996 1748 2016
```

But the thing is I must use `return` because I use a map thing to write it to file, but I get

```
map argument #1 must support iteration
```

Is there a solution to my problem?

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

def is_leap(year):
    leap = False

    if year % 4 == 0:
        if year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0:
            leap = True

    return leap

forward_list = {}
back_list = {}
newLst = []

def year_forward(yearBounds):
    for item in yearBounds:
        counter = 0
        # forwad list
        while not is_leap(item):
            item = item + 1
            counter += 1
        #forward_list.append(item)
        forward_list[item] = counter
    return forward_list


def year_backward(yearBounds):
    # back_list
    for item in yearBounds:
        counter = 0
        while not is_leap(item):
            item = item - 1
            counter -= 1
        #back_list.append(item)
        back_list[item] = counter
    return back_list

def findLastLeapYears(yearBounds):

    forward =  (year_forward(yearBounds))
    backward = (year_backward(yearBounds))
    tuple_forward = list(forward.items())
    tuple_backward = list(backward.items())

    counter = 0
    for item in tuple_forward:
        if abs(item[1]) < abs(tuple_backward[counter][1]):
            newLst.append (item[0])
            counter+=1
        elif abs(item[1]) == abs(tuple_backward[counter][1]):
            if item[0] < tuple_backward[counter][0]:
                newLst.append (item[0])
                counter += 1
            else:
                newLst.append (tuple_backward[counter][0])
                counter += 1

        else:
            newLst.append (tuple_backward[counter][0])
            counter+=1

    return newLst
```

The call:

```
leapYears = findLastLeapYears(years)

fptr.write(' '.join(map(str, leapYears)))
fptr.write('\n')

fptr.close()
```

Comment: Where is the code using map ?

Comment: You've shown us a bunch of functions, but not how those functions are **called** -- i.e. where is the main function?

Comment: wherever you are calling the map, you need to pass it a function OBJECT (no peranthesis) and a list (an iterable) of params to execute that function with. You are probably not doing so

Comment: I have added the call function to the code to show

Comment: what's the value of `leapYears` when `fptr.write(' '.join(map(str, leapYears)))` is called?

Comment: Simplify your code and create a [mcve]. Avoid using global variables. `newLst` should be declared in the function body of `findLastLeapYear`, for example. And confirm that you haven't used `str` as a variable name in the global scope. That would cause problems here.

Comment: When python raises an exception, you will get a traceback in your error output. Include the full traceback in the question. It contains essential information about how the error happened and where in your code you should look for a problem.

Comment: The error is not a compiler error. It is just that the `1996 1748 2016` is printing out when I want them in a separate line

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs fine, if you want it to be on separate line use `'\n'.join(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For me, using your code, I can't reproduce the error and everything works fine.

The error `map argument #1 must support iteration` suggests that you're using `str` as a variable or function that overwrites the default `str`.